# Remove all spaces from a string that are not enclosed in singlequotes or doublequotes

Tags: php, regex, string

I have short strings like this

```
$str = 'abc | xx ??   "1 x \' 3" d e f \' y " 5 \' x yz';
```

I want to remove all spaces from a string that are not enclosed in single or double quotes.
Any characters enclosed in single or double quotes should not be changed.
As a result, I expect:

```
$expected =  'abc|xx??"1 x \' 3"def\' y " 5 \'xyz';
```

My current solution based on character-wise comparisons is the following:

```
function removeSpaces($string){
  $ret = $stop = "";
  for($i=0; $i < strlen($string);$i++){
    $char = $string[$i];
    if($stop == "") {
      if($char == " ") continue;
      if($char == "'" OR $char == '"') $stop = $char;
    }
    else {
      if($char == $stop) $stop = "";
    }
    $ret .= $char;
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

Is there a solution that is smarter?

Comment: `d e f \' y` is enclosed by `"`, what's the rule here? You find the first quote and then, if/when you find the next quote you start do remove whitespace?

Comment: The handling is the same as with the PHP interpreter.
Single quotes enclosed in double quotes and double quotes enclosed in single quotes are treated like any other characters.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Please never post answers as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture either `"` or `'` in a group and consume any escaped variants or each until encountering the closing matching `'` or `"` using a backreference `\1`

```
(?<!\\)(['"])(?:(?!(?:\1|\\)).|\\.)*+\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\h+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/133d4x/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/OQen6)

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\\)` Negative lookbehind, assert not a `\` directly to the left
- `(['"])` capture **group 1**, match either `'` or `"`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!(?:\1|\\)).` If what is not directly to the right is either the value in group 1 or a backslash, match any char except a newline
  - `|` Or
  - `\\.` Match an escaped character
- `)*+` Close non capture group and repeat 1+ times
- `\1` Backreference to what is captured in group 1 (match up either `'` or `"`)
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Skip the match until now. [Read more about (*SKIP)(*FAIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex)
- `|` Or
- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars that you want to remove

As @[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) points out in his comment

> In some rare situations, this might match at a wrong position, namely,
> if there is a literal backslash (not an escaping one) before a
> single/double quoted string that should be skipped. You need to add
> (?:\{2})* after (?<!\)

The pattern would then be:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*(['"])(?:(?!(?:\1|\\)).|\\.)*+\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\h+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MrTwsJ/1)

Comment: Works perfectly for me too. I accept this solution because the regular expression is a bit shorter. Thank you.

Comment: @jspit In some rare situations, this might match at a wrong position, namely, if there is a literal backslash (not an escaping one) before a single/double quoted string that should be skipped. You need to add  `(?:\\{2})*` after `(?<!\\)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is a good point, in that case your pattern should be the accepted answer. +1

Comment: Both regular expressions fail with this string for me: "a\\'a b'" My string solution work fine for it. But I can rule out this rare situation for my application. Therefore I can use your solutions without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
preg_replace('~(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*(?:"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"|\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*\')(*SKIP)(?!)|\s+~s', '', $str)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/oIUST) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/idxaId/2).

**Details**

- `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*` - a check if there is no escaping `\` immediately on the left: any amount of double backslashes not preceded with `\`
- `(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')` - either a double- or single-quoted string literal allowing escape sequences
- `(*SKIP)(?!)` - skip the match and start a new search from the location where the regex failed
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces.

Note that a backslash in a single-quoted PHP string literal is used to form string escape sequences, and thus a literal backslash is "coded" with the help of double backslashes, and to match a literal backslash in text, two such backslashes are required, hence `"\\\\"` is used.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Was surprised that this is possible with a regular expression. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 3 step approach:

1. replace spaces in quote sections with placeholder
2. remove all spaces
3. restore spaces in quote sections

```
    $str = 'abc | xx ??   "1 x \' 3" d e f \' y " 5 \' x yz';
    echo 'input:  ' . $str . "\n";
    $result = preg_replace_callback( // replace spaces in quote sections with placeholder
        '|(["\'])(.*?)(\1)|',
        function ($matches) {
            $s = preg_replace('/ /', "\x01", $matches[2]);
            return $matches[1] . $s . $matches[3];
        },
        $str
    );
    $result = preg_replace('/ /', '', $result);     // remove all spaces
    $result = preg_replace('/\x01/', ' ', $result); // restore spaces in quote sections
    echo 'result: ' . $result;
    echo "\nexpect: " . 'abc|xx??"1 x \' 3"def\' y " 5 \'xyz';
```

Output:

```
input:  abc | xx ??   "1 x ' 3" d e f ' y " 5 ' x yz
result: abc|xx??"1 x ' 3"def' y " 5 'xyz
expect: abc|xx??"1 x ' 3"def' y " 5 'xyz
```

Explanation:

1. replace spaces in quote sections with placeholder

- use a `preg_replace_callback()`
- `'|(["\'])(.*?)(\1)|'` matches quote sections starting and ending with either `"` or `'`
- the `(\1)` makes sure to match the closing quote (either `"` or `'`)
- within the callback, use `preg_replace()` to replace all spaces with a non-printable replacement `"\x01"`

2. remove all spaces

- use `preg_replace()` to remove all spaces
- the replace does not match the replacement `"\x01"`, thus misses spaces in quote sections

3. restore spaces in quote sections

- use `preg_replace()` to restore all spaces from replacement `"\x01"`

Comment: I would not use a `preg_` that requires another `preg_` call to be nested inside it ...and also needs two more `preg_` calls to mop up at the end.  In what way do you think your new answer adds value to this page?

Comment: @mickmackusa: Because there is usually more than one answer to a question / I think it's good to give options. Let the reader decide what is useful and what is not.

Comment: But if you already know that your answer is less efficient (because it makes multiple `preg_` calls and the earlier answers only make 1 `preg_` call), then your answer will only waste researchers' time while they read an answer that provides no benefit.  So my question again to you is: What value does this less efficient, less direct, more verbose answer have over the other answers? Does it somehow provide improved accuracy? I don't know because I didn't test any of the answers, but I can virtually put money on Wiktor's answers being solid.

Comment: @mickmackusa: I agree, that for this particular use case the one line regex is easier, and likely faster. Value for this answer: Learning and education. There are use cases where multi-pass regexes make sense to solve complex problems effectively, such as parsing nested structures: https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Blog/BlogEntry201109x3